# Access redux store with variable value in name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

In my application I will have duplicates of the same object. Due to the advice of keeping the state as flat as possible I basically created multiple objects in my state that look like this:

```
const initialState = {
    test1: {},
    test2: {},
    test3: {},
}
```

I manage to connect to the store from my file but I have trouble when accessing the object I want, especially since I only know the index (1, 2, 3).

I have mapped the state to props:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    test1: state.test1,
    test2: state.test2,
    test3: state.test3,
  }
}
```

And I try to do something along those lines:

```
let index = 2;
let infos = this.props.[`test${index}`]
```

However this is not working and except doing some ugly switch on the index, I don't see another way of getting the object I want

Comment: An array isn't suitable?

Comment: You mean creating ```tests: []``` in the state and access with the index the element I want?

Comment: Does if work if you drop the second `.`: `this.props[`test${index}`]`

Comment: The problem with this is redux recommends to keep the state as flat as possible and avoid nested objects. I thought to explore that way before resorting to creating an array

Comment: To me if you're accessing by an index an array seems a better fit than composing an object key, especially if you want to map out the data in a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is trying to access the state object with the `this.props.` and then trying to evaluate a variable, you can do the following:

```
const index = 2;
const infos = this.props[`test${index}`];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
let index = 2;
let propname = `test${index}`;
let infos = this.props[propname]
```